# How can do multiple unique validation on Laravel 9?

Tags: php, validation, laravel-9

How can we do multiple unique validation?

Let me explain my problem through an example. Let's say I have a table. otherusers table. I have Country ID Number, Email and Phone number in this table.

While the user is registering, if there is a input record that fits all three, I want it not to save. So let's say

```
11111111111, mymail@domain.com, 0555 555 555 55(5)
```

There is such a record in the table. If someone wants to register with the same information, i want they can not to register. I want it will say that there is already a record with this information.

But if one of these information is different, it will be able to register. for example

```
11111111111, mymail@domain.com, 0555 555 555 55(6)
```

If he tries to register in as a user, he will be able to register.

Of course, the table is not like this. I'm giving this example to explain the process I'm looking for.

Here my table settings

```
///...
Schema::create('otherusers', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->string("CountryIDNumber",10);
     $table->string("Email",100);
     $table->string("Phone",15);
     $table->unique(['CountryIDNumber', 'Email', 'Phone'],"my_uniques");
}
///...
```

and here my store function in controller.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'CountryIDNumber' => 'required|max:10|unique:other_users',
            'Email' => 'required|max:100|unique:other_users',
            'Phone' => 'required|max:15|unique:other_users',
        ]);
        $data = $request->all();

        OtherUsers::Create($data);
        return redirect()->route('otherusers.show'); // stok listesi sayfası
    }
```

If I give it unique for each row as above it will check for each independently.
However, I want to do validation in accordance with the index I have given here. If there is a line with the same three information entered from outside, the record should not be made.

And how can I show this error on the front side. I am using below codes to show validation errors

```
        @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        @endif
```

The index I added to the table is working. When I try to make a recording I get the following error.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '11111111111-mymail@domain.com-0555 555 555 555' for key 'my_uniques'
```

How can I do this what I want?
I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding it as a new answer so that [Christoph's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4503776/christoph) comment remains in response.

I changed my first answer with the codes below.
(I deleted the selection query code and changed the controls from (If) to (Try Catch))

```
        try {
             MyModel::Create($data);
             return redirect()->route('show');
        } catch (\exception $th) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['This record has been insert before.']);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How can i solve this...
I am writing how I solved this problem in case anyone else has it.
I wrote a query that gets the number of records that match the conditions.

```
$checkcount = DB::select("select count(*) as count from table where .....");
```

And by checking this number with if, I sent an error message if there is a record, that is, if it is greater than 0.

```
if ($checkcount[0]->count === 0) {
 MyModel::Create($data);
 return redirect()->route('show');
}
else {
  return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['This record has been insert before.']);
}
```

This error message is naturally displayed on the front-end (blade codes I gave above).

Comment: This approach makes you vulnerable to race conditions. If another entry is inserted after your `SELECT`, but before the `INSERT`, you will have duplicate entries. The better way is to use a composite unique key, and just try to `INSERT` your data. If the database throws an exception you know that another entry with that data already exists.

Comment: My table already has indexes. It cannot be a duplicate record in any way. When I try to add duplicate records, laravel already gives me duplicate record error.
I don't know why, but I used if instead of Try catch. I will edit my codes. You woke me up, thanks :D